# Variable Scope in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, scope

In c++, any variables declared in main will be available throughout main right? I mean if the variables were declared in a try loop, will they would still be accessible throughout main?
Because I have declared several variables in a try loop in main, but if I use them in any other part of main outside the try loop, I get a "was not declared in this scope" error

I unfortunately can't post my actual code but this is basically what I am doing

```
int main()
{
   try 
   {
     int number = 0;
   }

   catch (...)
   {
     cout <<"Error";
   }

   number ++;
   cout <<number;

   return 0;
}
```

I would basically get an error on line 13 and 14 saying number wasn't declared in this scope.

Comment: The answer should be clear from the compile error message, no? ☕

Comment: Do you have any compile error when you put `int number = 0;` out of `try{}` ?

Answer (score 7):

The scope of `number` is limited to the `try` block. Pull out this declaration to the `main` scope to access the variable after the `try` block:

```
int main()
{
   int number = 0;
   try 
   {
     // do something...
   }

   catch (...)
   {
     cout <<"Error";
   }

   number ++;
   cout <<number;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the variables to be accessible throughout main and by in a try block - how would i do this? I don't want to make the variables global, because I don't want access to by other functions.

Comment: @user1017485: it's not global here, it's still within `main`, but outside the `try` block.

Comment: `number` is already available inside `try` block and all rest of `main` that follows the declaration of `number` (i.e. `int number = 0;`).

Comment: @user1017485: What Xion is doing doesn't make it global, his re-write of your function makes the number only usable in main.

Comment: i know that Im just saying I want the variable to be declared in a try loop (because it allocates memory on the heap in my program so i want to catch any bad_alloc expcetions) but I also want it to be accessible throughout main without making it global

Comment: @user1017485: Your question doesn't state that declaring your variable allocates memory, and your simplified example eliminates this key point. This is why it's important to post *actual* code that you're using, instead of an abbreviated example.

Comment: im sorry should i still put in a try block though? (since it allocates memory?)

Answer (score 6):

Local variables in C++ have block scope, not function scope. The variable `number` is only in scope inside the `try` block.

To make this work, you have (at least) two choices:

1. Make the variable accessible at function scope (not so good):

   ```
   int main() {
       int number;
       try {
           number = <some possibly-exception-throwing call>;
       } catch (...) {
           cout << "Error\n";
           return 0;
       }
       ++number;
       cout << number;
   }
   ```
2. Place all use of the variable inside the try scope (much better):

   ```
   int main() {
       try {
           int number = <some possibly-exception-throwing call>;
           ++number;
           cout << number;
       } catch (...) {
           cout << "Error\n";
       }
   }
   ```

I strongly favour the second choice, for a few reasons:

1. You don't have to explicitly handle the case that the variable wasn't initialised correctly.
2. There's no risk of accidentally using the uninitialised variable. In fact, your code would exhibit precisely this bug if C++ locals had function scope (assuming the intent was to initialise `number` with something more interesting than a constant).
3. It keeps declaration and initialisation together.

---

Appendix: For `main()` in particular, there's a third choice:

```
    int main() try {
        ...
    } catch {
        cout << "Error\n";
    }
```

This wraps the entire program, including static initialisers outside of `main()` proper, in a try...catch.

Comment: Thanks but I need the variables to be accessible throughout main and by in a try block - how would i do this? I don't want to make the variables global, because I don't want access to by other functions.

Comment: I'd say this is a real good answer, from what I understood from the rest of the comments this accomplishes what the poster wants. Even if he doesn't seem to get it himself. Otherwise I would have asked if it was possible to separate declaration from initialization since it was suggested that it was a pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

> In c++, any variables declared in main will be available throughout
>   main right?

No!

The scope of every variable is the block where the variable defined and its nested blocks : `{}`

You must put `int number;` outside the `try{}` block.

---

More on [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/):

> Scope of variables All the variables that we intend to use in a
>   program must have been declared with its type specifier in an earlier
>   point in the code, like we did in the previous code at the beginning
>   of the body of the function main when we declared that a, b, and
>   result were of type int.
>
> A variable can be either of global or local scope. A global variable
>   is a variable declared in the main body of the source code, outside
>   all functions, while a local variable is one declared within the body
>   of a function or a block.
>
> [image]
>
> Global variables can be referred from anywhere in the code, even
>   inside functions, whenever it is after its declaration.
>
> The scope of local variables is limited to the block enclosed in
>   braces ({}) where they are declared. For example, if they are declared
>   at the beginning of the body of a function (like in function main)
>   their scope is between its declaration point and the end of that
>   function. In the example above, this means that if another function
>   existed in addition to main, the local variables declared in main
>   could not be accessed from the other function and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks but I need the variables to be accessible throughout main and by in a try block - how would i do this? I don't want to make the variables global, because I don't want access to by other functions.

Comment: Put it outside of `try{}` after `int main(){`.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal; each `{ ... }` block mark a new scope, and variables declared inside it are local to it. If you want `number` to be available throughout all `main` declare it outside the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks but I need the variables to be accessible throughout main and by in a try block - how would i do this? I don't want to make the variables global, because I don't want access to by other functions.

Comment: Declare it at `main` level, it will be visible also inside the `try` block. In C++ variables declared at outer scopes are visible at inner scopes (unless they are shadowed by "more local" variables with the same name).